# Converting a float in chars to float (PYTHON)

Tags: python, floating-point, byte, valueconverter

I have a program in python in which I want to receive a frame with some values. This values are sent by a xbee.

Xbee send a float splitted in 4 bytes by a union struct, something like this:

```
typedef union _data{
    float f;
    char s[4];
} myFloat;
```

So for example, 17.23 gives me 10, -41, -119, 65. So, I have to recover all these values in python and after I got 4, convert them into a float. What do I have to do since I read each one (serial.read()) to get the float resultant?

Those values will be received by python script and I want to join them again into a float. I read about struct in python but I am not good skill in python and I don't understand how it works.

I read bytes one by one using serial.read.

Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear what's giving you trouble.  If you read four bytes and put them into a string `s`, then you can convert them into `(10, -41, -119, 65)` using `struct.unpack('4b', s)`, and into a float by `struct.unpack('f', s)[0]` (the `[0]` is necessary because you'll get a 1-element tuple back, not a float.)  Does that help?

Comment: But, how can I set bytes in a string? I tried: s = [10, -41, -119, 65]
print struct.unpack('f', s)[0]
But it tells me it requires a string argumentof length 4... How can I read 4 bytes and save them in an string array?

Comment: I thought you always had the float packed into chars, and wanted to turn those chars into a float?  Anyway, if you have a list of numbers, you can pack them into a string using `struct.pack`: try `n = [10, -41, -119, 65]` and then `struct.pack('4b', *n)` to get a four-byte string.  I think you should edit your question to make it more clear what you have now and what you want to end up with.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Is this Python 3 or Python 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're getting the four integers `[10, -41, -119, 65]` and you want to reassemble those into the original float.  If so, the answer is already contained in @DSM's comments.  Piecing the bits together:

```
>>> import struct
>>> x = [10, -41, -119, 65]
>>> struct.unpack('<f', struct.pack('4b', *x))[0]
17.229999542236328
```

Note that we're not getting *exactly* `17.23` here, because that number isn't exactly representable as a single-precision IEEE 754 binary float.

This sounds a little topsy-turvy, though:  it should be easier to get the original bytes that to get 4 integers.  How exactly are you getting the integer values?  If you're using pyserial, couldn't you just do a `read(4)` to get 4 bytes at once and then use `struct.unpack` directly on the result of that?  E.g., I'd expect something like this to work (simulated interpreter session):

```
>>> import struct
>>> x_bytes = ser.read(4)  # (where ser is your Serial instance)
>>> x = struct.unpack('<f', x_bytes)[0]
>>> x
17.229999542236328
```

Comment: I didn't know more than one byte can be read at the same time. I will try this.

Comment: I have discovered I have a problem with reading 4 values directly. Because of my xbee use AP=2, they have escaped characters. So maybe sometimes a receive character doesn't represent the real value or even just represent the escaped character inserted before it... So I guess I have to check every byte read before putting it on the struct... Can I extract just one byte inserted in that struct for checking it? This way, I can read 4, check them and know if one of them is wrong to modify it and read another one...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with xbee.  Maybe someone else can help here?  Or you could ask this as a new question.  It sounds as though the issue of getting 4 bytes and getting around escaping is orthogonal to the one of reconstructing a float, so might make a good separate SO question.